# Listing files in a windows directory not working in C

Tags: c, windows, list, dir

I have this code in my program:

```
char * choosePic(const char * dir)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fdFile;
    HANDLE hFind = null;
    char sPath[2048];

    sprintf(sPath, "%s\\*.*", dir);

    if ((hFind = FindFirstFile((LPCWSTR) sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            printf("File not found");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error with path")
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
        return NULL;
    }

    do
    {
        if (strcmp((char *) fdFile.cFileName, "*.*") != 0 && strcmp((char *) fdFile.cFileName, ".." != 0)
        {
            printf("%s %s", sPath, dir);
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile));

    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

I give this function a path, `choosePic("C:\\Windows")`, and I only get:

```
> Error with path
```

I tried so many things, even running with admin rights.
Nothing works.

Comment: Which error code are you getting from the Win32 API?

Comment: `(LPCWSTR) sPath` - sPath is not a wide string, so casting it to one isn't going to make anything work.  If you're compiling for Unicode then use it properly, or switch to a multibyte application.

Comment: I don't need Unicode. So what should I do with sPath? Because removing the cast gives an error. Error code is 3.

Comment: Again, people randomly use casts that they don't understand, just to shut up the compilers, and then find out things don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the casts that you are using, it looks like your project is set to Unicode (Project Properties -- Configuration Properties\General), in that case your `char` variables need to be changed to wide character`wchar_t` and the `sprintf()`, `strcmp()` and `printf()` functions need to be changed to their Unicode equivalents -- **always be aware that you are probably doing something wrong when you have to use casts!**

Alternatively, you can change the project to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`...